# How can I save an instance of a class in it's own class as a class variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to define a class that has an instance of itself as a class variable so I can reference a common instance of it all over the place.

How can I get something like this to work?

```
class Point():
  ORIGIN = Point()

  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

p0 = Point.ORIGIN
p1 = Point(3,4)

distance = (p1.x*p1.x + p1.y*p1.y) ** .5
print(distance)
```

Comment: If you need a "common instance," you're probably looking for static variables/methods.

Comment: Side note: You're reinventing `math.hypot`, except yours is less accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the class attribute *after* the class has been created:

```
class Point():
  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

Point.ORIGIN = Point()
```

You can probably also make it work so that the origin is created lazily via descriptors, or you can probably do something funky using a metaclass -- but that seems unlikely to be worth your while.

Comment: Thanks for the practical solution! I'm disappointed attaching ORIGIN has to happen at the very bottom after a potentially long class definition, but it seems that's the best way to go without getting more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a meta class:

```
>>> class SingletonMeta(type):
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
...         cls.ORIGIN = cls()
...
>>> class Point(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
...     def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...
>>> p0 = Point.ORIGIN
>>> p1 = Point(3,4)
>>> p0
<__main__.Point object at 0x110b7e7b8>
>>> p0.x, p0.y
(0, 0)
```

Comment: This looks like a valuable thing to know. Can you tell us more about how a metaclass works, or when its constructor gets called?

Comment: @JoshOrndorff -- Metaclass constructors are called when a class is being created.  e.g. in this case, `SingletonMeta.__new__` is called to _create_ the `Point` class.  `SingletonMeta.__init__` is called immediately after `Point` is created.  [You can read a lot more about metaclasses in this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Simply create class variables that represent the values you want instead of encapsulating those values in an instance:

```
class Point:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

x,y = Point.x, Point.y
p1 = Point(3,4)
distance = ((p1.x-x)**2 + (p1.y-y)**2) ** .5
print(distance) # prints 5.0
```

Or, better yet:

```
class Point:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance(self, other=None):
        if other is None:
            x,y = Point.x, Point.y
        else:
            x,y = other.x, other.y
        return ((self.x-x)**2 + (self.y-y)**2) ** .5
```

And then you can do this:

```
>>> p1 = Point(3,4)
>>> p1.distance()
5.0
>>> p1.distance(Point(3,5))
1.0
```